# How do I number appendix longtables and include them in the *ToC*?

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering, captions, longtable, appendices

I am writing my PhD dissertation. 
I have many appendices (like 6?), mostly tables.

As it happens automatically for tables and figures, I'd like to get a label plus progressive number before I define the title of the appendix on the top of the appendix page. Something like

Appendix 1: Bla bla bla.

Also, I'd like my appendix titles to be included in the ToC.

This is what I have:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{file}{sec_unit}{entry}

\begin{appendices}

\appendix{Cities Coordinates\label{appendix:Cities Coordinates}}
\begin{longtable}{ l l r r}
\toprule
\textsc{County}&\textsc{City}&\textsc{Latitude}&\textsc{Longitude}\\ \midrule
\endfirsthead
\caption[]{(continued)}\\
\toprule
\textsc{County}&\textsc{City}&\textsc{Latitude}&\textsc{Longitude}\\ \midrule
\endhead
\bottomrule
\endlastfoot
Alameda&Alameda&-122.24&37.76\\
&Albany&-122.29&37.88\\
&Berkeley&-122.27&37.87\\
&Dublin&-121.93&37.70\\
&Hayward&-122.08&37.66\\
&Emeryville&-122.28&37.83\\
&Oakland&-122.27&37.80\\
&Piedmont&-122.23&37.82\\
&San Leandro&-122.15&37.72\\
&Union City&-122.04&37.59\\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

---

I still have some problems with the appendices:

1. In the ToC I see only three appendixes represented, but I am
   providing four instead;
2. I don't know where to type the title of my appendices so that it comes out uniformly, no matter if the appendix is a table or a list of examples;
3. I would like the title of my appendix in the landscaped page to be at the top of the page.

Thank you in advance. And yes, I use **longtables** because I have a long list of data to display.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{covington}
\usepackage[danish,english]{babel}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{includefoot=false, heightrounded=true, top=4.5cm, bottom=6cm, left=4.7cm, right=4.7cm} 
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{caption}
\newif\ifappendix % snippet appendix
\makeatletter
\def\LT@c@ption#1[#2]#3{%
  \LT@makecaption#1\fnum@table{#3}%
  \def\@tempa{#2}%
  \ifx\@tempa\@empty\else
     {\let\\\space
     \addcontentsline{\ifappendix toc\else lot\fi}{table}{\protect\numberline{\thetable}{#2}}}%
  \fi}
\makeatother
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{morefloats}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{2cm}}
\setlength\belowcaptionskip{1\baselineskip} 
\usepackage{lscape} 

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{arabic}  
\tableofcontents
 \addcontentsline{file}{sec_unit}{entry}

\chapter{How Do I Make a Nice Appendix?}

\section{Please Advise}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. 

\begin{appendices}
\appendixtrue

\setcounter{table}{0}
\renewcommand*{\thetable}{A.\arabic{table}}

\begin{longtable}{ l l r r}
\caption{text text\label{appendix:this is just the table caption. I would like this to be something like: Appendix A.1: bla bla bla}}\\
\toprule
\textsc{text}&\textsc{text}&\textsc{text}&\textsc{text}\\ \midrule
\endfirsthead
\caption[]{(continued)}\\
\toprule
\textsc{text}&\textsc{text}&\textsc{text}&\textsc{text}\\ \midrule
\endhead
\bottomrule
\endlastfoot
text&text&123&123\\
&text&123&123\\
&text&123&123\\
text&text&123&123\\
&text&123&123\\
&text&123&123\\
text&text&123&123\\
&text&123&123\\
&text&123&123\\
text&text&123&123\\
&text&123&123\\
&text&123&123\\
text&text&123&123\\
&text&123&123\\
&text&123&123\\
text&text&123&123\\
&text&123&123\\
&text&123&123\\
text&text&123&123\\
&text&123&123\\
&text&123&123\\
text&text&123&123\\
&text&123&123\\
&text&123&123\\
text&text&123&123\\
&text&123&123\\
&text&123&123\\
text&text&123&123\\
&text&123&123\\
&text&123&123\\
text&text&123&123\\
&text&123&123\\
&text&123&123\\
text&text&123&123\\
&text&123&123\\
&text&123&123\\
text&text&123&123\\
&text&123&123\\
&text&123&123\\
text&text&123&123\\
&text&123&123\\
&text&123&123\\
text&text&123&123\\
&text&123&123\\
&text&123&123\\
text&text&123&123\\
&text&123&123\\
&text&123&123\\
text&text&123&123\\
&text&123&123\\
&text&123&123\\
text&text&123&123\\
&text&123&123\\
&text&123&123\\
\end{longtable}

\newpage
\appendixtrue
\setcounter{table}{1}
\renewcommand*{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{longtable}{l l l l}
\caption{this is a table caption that I would like to print at the top of my page\label{appendix:this is a table caption that I would like to print at the top of my page}}\\
\toprule
\textsc{text}&\textsc{text}&\textsc{text}&\textsc{website}\\ 
\midrule
\endfirsthead
\caption[]{(continued)}\\
\toprule
\textsc{text}&\textsc{text}&\textsc{text}&\textsc{website}\\ 
\midrule
\endhead
\bottomrule
\endlastfoot
text&text&text&www.nytimes.com\\
text&text&text&www.nytimes.com\\
text&text&text&www.nytimes.com\\
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}

\newpage
\appendixtrue
\setcounter{table}{2}
\renewcommand*{\thetable}{A.\arabic{table}}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{longtable}{l l l r r r r r}
\caption{text\label{appendix:text3}}\\
\toprule
\textsc{text}&\textsc{text}&\textsc{text}&\textsc{text}&number&number&number&number\\
\midrule
\endfirsthead
\caption[]{(continued)}\\
\toprule
\textsc{text}&\textsc{text}&\textsc{text}&\textsc{text}&number&number&number&number\\
\midrule
\endhead
\bottomrule
\endfoot
text&text&text&text&number&number&number&number\\
text&text&text&text&number&number&number&number\\
text&text&text&text&number&number&number&number\\
text&text&text&text&number&number&number&number\\
text&text&text&text&number&number&number&number\\
text&text&text&text&number&number&number&number\\
text&text&text&text&number&number&number&number\\
text&text&text&text&number&number&number&number\\
text&text&text&text&number&number&number&number\\
text&text&text&text&number&number&number&number\\
text&text&text&text&number&number&number&number\\
text&text&text&text&number&number&number&number\\
text&text&text&text&number&number&number&number\\
text&text&text&text&number&number&number&number\\
text&text&text&text&number&number&number&number\\
text&text&text&text&number&number&number&number\\
text&text&text&text&number&number&number&number\\
text&text&text&text&number&number&number&number\\
text&text&text&text&number&number&number&number\\
text&text&text&text&number&number&number&number\\
text&text&text&text&number&number&number&number\\
text&text&text&text&number&number&number&number\\
text&text&text&text&number&number&number&number\\
text&text&text&text&number&number&number&number\\
text&text&text&text&number&number&number&number\\

\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}

\newpage
\appendixtrue
\setcounter{table}{3}
\renewcommand*{\thetable}{A.\arabic{table}}
\appendix{I would like this to be Appendix A.4: bla bla bla\label{appendix:I would like this to be Appendix A.4: bla bla bla}}
\begin{examples}
\item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. \label{ex:Lorem}
\item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.\label{ex:ipsum}
\end{examples}

\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took the new example provided by the OP and added/changed the following:

- I enclosed the `examples` environment in a `minipage` and put the `minipage` into a (single-column) longtable (requirement 1);
- `\renewcommand*{\tablename}{Appendix}` at the start of the appendix provides the desired caption format (requirement 2);
- I removed the recurring instances of `\appendixtrue\setcounter{table}{<value>}` etc. because there's no need for them.

I don't have a clue with regard to requirement 3 (rotated longtables with non-rotated captions).

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{covington}
\usepackage[danish,english]{babel}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{includefoot=false, heightrounded=true, top=4.5cm, bottom=6cm, left=4.7cm, right=4.7cm} 
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{caption}
\newif\ifappendix % snippet appendix
\makeatletter
\def\LT@c@ption#1[#2]#3{%
  \LT@makecaption#1\fnum@table{#3}%
  \def\@tempa{#2}%
  \ifx\@tempa\@empty\else
     {\let\\\space
     \addcontentsline{\ifappendix toc\else lot\fi}{table}{\protect\numberline{\thetable}{#2}}}%
  \fi}
\makeatother
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{morefloats}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{2cm}}
\setlength\belowcaptionskip{1\baselineskip} 
\usepackage{lscape} 

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{arabic}  
\tableofcontents
 \addcontentsline{file}{sec_unit}{entry}

\chapter{How Do I Make a Nice Appendix?}

\section{Please Advise}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. 

\begin{appendices}
\appendixtrue

\setcounter{table}{0}
\renewcommand*{\thetable}{A.\arabic{table}}

\renewcommand*{\tablename}{Appendix}

\begin{longtable}{ l l r r}
\caption{this is just the table caption. I would like this to be something like: Appendix A.1: bla bla bla\label{appendix:text1}}\\
\toprule
\textsc{text}&\textsc{text}&\textsc{text}&\textsc{text}\\ \midrule
\endfirsthead
\caption[]{(continued)}\\
\toprule
\textsc{text}&\textsc{text}&\textsc{text}&\textsc{text}\\ \midrule
\endhead
\bottomrule
\endlastfoot
text&text&123&123\\
&text&123&123\\
&text&123&123\\
text&text&123&123\\
&text&123&123\\
&text&123&123\\
text&text&123&123\\
&text&123&123\\
&text&123&123\\
text&text&123&123\\
&text&123&123\\
&text&123&123\\
text&text&123&123\\
&text&123&123\\
&text&123&123\\
text&text&123&123\\
&text&123&123\\
&text&123&123\\
text&text&123&123\\
&text&123&123\\
&text&123&123\\
text&text&123&123\\
&text&123&123\\
&text&123&123\\
text&text&123&123\\
&text&123&123\\
&text&123&123\\
text&text&123&123\\
&text&123&123\\
&text&123&123\\
text&text&123&123\\
&text&123&123\\
&text&123&123\\
text&text&123&123\\
&text&123&123\\
&text&123&123\\
text&text&123&123\\
&text&123&123\\
&text&123&123\\
text&text&123&123\\
&text&123&123\\
&text&123&123\\
text&text&123&123\\
&text&123&123\\
&text&123&123\\
text&text&123&123\\
&text&123&123\\
&text&123&123\\
text&text&123&123\\
&text&123&123\\
&text&123&123\\
text&text&123&123\\
&text&123&123\\
&text&123&123\\
\end{longtable}

\newpage

\begin{landscape}
\begin{longtable}{l l l l}
\caption{this is a table caption that I would like to print at the top of my page\label{appendix:text2}}\\
\toprule
\textsc{text}&\textsc{text}&\textsc{text}&\textsc{website}\\ 
\midrule
\endfirsthead
\caption[]{(continued)}\\
\toprule
\textsc{text}&\textsc{text}&\textsc{text}&\textsc{website}\\ 
\midrule
\endhead
\bottomrule
\endlastfoot
text&text&text&www.nytimes.com\\
text&text&text&www.nytimes.com\\
text&text&text&www.nytimes.com\\
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}

\newpage

\begin{landscape}
\begin{longtable}{l l l r r r r r}
\caption{text\label{appendix:text3}}\\
\toprule
\textsc{text}&\textsc{text}&\textsc{text}&\textsc{text}&number&number&number&number\\
\midrule
\endfirsthead
\caption[]{(continued)}\\
\toprule
\textsc{text}&\textsc{text}&\textsc{text}&\textsc{text}&number&number&number&number\\
\midrule
\endhead
\bottomrule
\endfoot
text&text&text&text&number&number&number&number\\
text&text&text&text&number&number&number&number\\
text&text&text&text&number&number&number&number\\
text&text&text&text&number&number&number&number\\
text&text&text&text&number&number&number&number\\
text&text&text&text&number&number&number&number\\
text&text&text&text&number&number&number&number\\
text&text&text&text&number&number&number&number\\
text&text&text&text&number&number&number&number\\
text&text&text&text&number&number&number&number\\
text&text&text&text&number&number&number&number\\
text&text&text&text&number&number&number&number\\
text&text&text&text&number&number&number&number\\
text&text&text&text&number&number&number&number\\
text&text&text&text&number&number&number&number\\
text&text&text&text&number&number&number&number\\
text&text&text&text&number&number&number&number\\
text&text&text&text&number&number&number&number\\
text&text&text&text&number&number&number&number\\
text&text&text&text&number&number&number&number\\
text&text&text&text&number&number&number&number\\
text&text&text&text&number&number&number&number\\
text&text&text&text&number&number&number&number\\
text&text&text&text&number&number&number&number\\
text&text&text&text&number&number&number&number\\

\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}

\newpage

\begin{longtable}{l}
\caption{I would like this to be Appendix A.4: bla bla bla\label{appendix:text4}}\\
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\begin{examples}
\item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. \label{ex:Lorem}
\item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.\label{ex:ipsum}
\end{examples}
\end{minipage}
\end{longtable}

\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that assumes chapters in the main text, but no chapters in the appendix -- only an "Appendices"  starting page and some tables. As those tables should go into the normal ToC (!), I patched the `\LT@c@ption` command to include a test for the new `\ifappendix` boolean switch. Note that tables by default are formatted as sections in the ToC/LoT.

EDIT: After some discussion in chat, here's a hack that works (only) for `longtable`s, but also if the `caption` and `hyperref` packages are loaded. ("Hack" because I basically revert `caption`s changes to `longtable`s LoT entries.)

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}

\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{caption}

\newif\ifappendix

\makeatletter

\def\LT@c@ption#1[#2]#3{%
  \LT@makecaption#1\fnum@table{#3}%
  \def\@tempa{#2}%
  \ifx\@tempa\@empty\else
     {\let\\\space
     \addcontentsline{\ifappendix toc\else lot\fi}{table}{\protect\numberline{\thetable}{#2}}}%
  \fi}

\makeatother

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\listoftables

\chapter{First}

\section{First-first}

Some text. See also table~\ref{tab:testl}.

\begin{longtable}{c}
(Some tabular material)\\
\caption{A longtable}\\
\end{longtable}

\begin{appendices}

\appendixtrue

\setcounter{table}{0}
\renewcommand*{\thetable}{A.\arabic{table}}

\begin{longtable}{c}
(Some tabular material)\\
\caption{An appendix longtable}\label{tab:testl}\\
\end{longtable}

\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. Now I have Table A.1 etc, which is nice, and I have a way to refer to them in my dissertation. There's nothing in my ToC, though. I'd like my appendices to be listed there.

Comment: @Costi I re-checked my example, and table A.1 *does* show up in the ToC as requested. Did you compile several times? Have you copy-pasted parts of my code into your actual document, and missed something in the process (e.g., setting `\appendixtrue` at the start of the `appendices` environment)?

Comment: \appendixtrue is there. I have compiled several times. I have this in my preamble (maybe it conflicts?) \usepackage{tocvsec2}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

Comment: @Costi You should have mentioned `tocvsec2`. I did some quick tests and my example still works with the package added, but that doesn't mean there aren't problems in your actual document. Try to remove `\usepackage{tocvsec2}` there.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention tocvsec2 earlier. I wasn't aware of what that was.

Comment: I now realize that after lockstep code I have the list of appendix tables in the list of tables, also with tocvsec2 activated. I'd like the list of the appendix to be in the ToC, not in the List of Tables. But that's ok, if it's too complicate I can give up there. It's good that I have a list of them somewhere and that I have a way to refer to them now. Thanks

Comment: @Costi Doy you use `longtable` for your appendix tables? This could be the explanation!

Comment: Yes, I use longtable for most of them; then my last appendix is a list of examples, and in fact there are some idiosyncrasies with that. Examples don't have captions (where should I put the appendix title in this case?) and they won't come out in the List of Tables. Can't I just have a list of appendices in the ToC, just like I have a list of Chapters and Sections there?

Comment: @Costi Answer updated to work with `longtable`. Re "examples": There's no list of appendices, only of chapters/sections, tables, figures, and possibly special environments like examples. Please consider to ask a follow-up question at our site.

Comment: @Costi Answer updated again.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4434/discussion-between-costi-and-lockstep)