# Includegraphics in the Appendix

Tags: graphics, appendices

The present question is related to [this previous one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66369/how-do-i-number-appendix-longtables-and-include-them-in-the-toc).

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}
\pagestyle{headings}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{covington}
\usepackage[danish,english]{babel}
\usepackage{pslatex}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{typearea}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{includefoot=false, heightrounded=true, top=4.5cm, bottom=6cm, left=4.7cm, right=4.7cm} 
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{caption}
\newif\ifappendix % snippet appendice
\makeatletter
\def\LT@c@ption#1[#2]#3{%
  \LT@makecaption#1\fnum@table{#3}%
  \def\@tempa{#2}%
  \ifx\@tempa\@empty\else
     {\let\\\space
     \addcontentsline{\ifappendix toc\else lot\fi}{table}{\protect\numberline{\thetable}{#2}}}%
  \fi}
\makeatother
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{morefloats}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{2cm}}
\usepackage[bottom,norule]{footmisc}
\setlength\belowcaptionskip{1\baselineskip} 

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
 \addcontentsline{file}{sec_unit}{entry}
 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}

\chapter{Lorem}

Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum.

\begin{appendices}

\appendixtrue
\setcounter{table}{0}
\renewcommand*{\thetable}{A.\arabic{table}}
\renewcommand*{\tablename}{Appendix}

\begin{figure}[H]\centering
\includegraphics[scale=1]{pic1.jpg} \caption{Metonymy}.\label{fig:Metonymy}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]\centering
\includegraphics[scale=1]{pic2.jpg} \caption{Synonymy}.\label{fig:Synonymy}
\end{figure}

\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

My MWE outputs an appendix with two figures and no Appendix title. 
Besides the figure names, I would like to have an Appendix title at the top of the page. 
Something like the following does not work here because I have captions for the figures already.

```
\caption{Example\label{appendix: Example}}\
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `\chapter{A nice appendix}` to get an appendix title.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, this will attribute the same title "A nice appendix" to all of my other appendices.

Comment: Also, as you can see, I have a nice snippet created by lockstep that makes my appendices titles available in the ToC. Using \chapter won't allow me to have the appendix title in the ToC.

Comment: @Costi --- In order: no it won't, and yes it will. You just need to add a separate `\chapter` command to generate each appendix title. They appeared in the toc when I tried this with your example.